# User Select of Payment Processor in Webform fails to complete transaction

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor

Using Webform CiviCRM to register participants in Event. Using Civi 5.21 with Stripe processor.   Transaction will work if Payment processor set in Civi tab to be only Stripe or if processor is only Pay Later.   If set to User Select the transaction does not complete - does not show in Webform Results or become an event registration.

Errors in ConfigAndLog include 
[warning] Deprecated Path: There is a setting (generate_schema_and_data) not correctly defined. You may see unpredictability due to this. CRM_Core_Setting::setItems
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Other ConfigAndLog  include Feb 28 17:23:06  [debug] Pay by Credit Card Exception: Event: charge.refunded Error: No matching contributions for event evt_1GHC2YLNY7Ta5lgY9zEhkw8C and warnings (not clear if these are directly or indirectly related)

Feb 27 14:21:00  [warning] Deprecated code: We have merged input params into the property bag for now but please rewrite code to not use this.

Feb 27 14:21:00  [warning] Deprecated code: Unknown property 'amount'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties

Feb 27 14:21:04  [warning] Deprecated function ::civicrm_api3_contribution_transact, use The contibution.transact api is unsupported & known to have issues. Please see the section at the bottom of https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/financial/OrderAPI/ for getting off it.
Array

Comment: What CMS, stripe extension version are you using?

Comment: Drupal 7.69, Civi 5.21, Stripe 6.3

Comment: I think this issue may be closer related to this https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3108529 - will try to get the corrected version that is referenced on the drupal project discussion

Comment: Updated webform_civicrm to most recent - https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm - initial testing seems to indicate problem resolved.

Comment: Continuing this issue, problem resurfaced.    Installed version 6.3.2 of Stripe extension which also seems to work, again based on initial testing.   Sorry not able to provide definitive solution but hope this helps.